# Place index.php under public folder in ubuntu 16.04 LTS using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

I've tried a lot o tutorials, searched and researched on stackoverflow and other websites, but I still don't manage to fix this problem.
Here's it. 
This is my folder structure and the.htaccess and index.php files:

[file structure | .htaccess | index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeYVt.png)

When I try to access php built in server (sudo php -S localhost:800) I get this:

[Php built-in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVMz1.png)

When using apache2 I get the folder structure like this:

[Apache Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf6j8.png)

I have also tried to change the DirectoryIndex to public/index.php, but when typing a query string (SEO friendly with slashes instead of ex.:?a=2) I get an error, the server says for example:

***The requested resource /mvc-oop/home/id/2 was not found on this server.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the servers you are using are not configured to point to the correct directory that contains your index.php entry file.

Firstly, .htaccess files are used by the Apache web server as a configuration file. This configuration file is not understood or read by all web server software. In other words: .htaccess works with Apache, but won't work with your php server.

In the .htaccess file amend the last line so it contains a valid relative path beginning with `./`

```
ReWriteRule ^ ./public/index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The **./public** translates to: " Starting in the current directory, descend into the child folder named public..."

Comment: Hey bro, thanks a lot, a put it this way, but it is working only on apache, not in php built-in server, but that's awesome, thank you again:  
  `DirectoryIndex public/index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

ReWriteRule ^ ./public/index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Yes, it is, only in apache! But it's enough for the time being.

Comment: Gustavo, the .htaccess file is an apache only solution to redirecting. It will not work with the php server.

Comment: Oh yah, got it!!